# Not Allowed to Create User with GRANT

Tags: mysql

I was trying to install wordpress on ubuntu using the link and struck at  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#4-configure-database

When I run this command,I get the error-

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER
    -> ON wordpress.*
    -> TO wordpress@localhost
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'root';


ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'root'' at line 1
```

I tried almost every syntax by changing the `wordpress@localhost` to `'wordpress'@'localhost'`

I tried removing and adding the APOSTROPHE on `'root'` in `IDENTIFIED BY 'root'`,

then after searching I tried this command as well - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root`'  and got

Error - `ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT`

Nothing found working for me. Please help where am doing mistake. Thanks

P.S. Database is already there -

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| wordpress          |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You needn't include the `IDENTIFIED BY` bit when granting privileges. If you need to create a user *and* grant permissions, that's two operations:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '{superSecretPassword!123}';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON `wordpress`.* TO 'wordpress'@'localhost';
```

Be sure to change the `superSecretPassword!123` bit to something better.

Comment: User not created, 0 rows affected !!

Comment: If an account was not created, there should be another line explaining *why* it was not created (already exists, `mysql_native_password` is not defined, etc.). You will also need to be connected to your database with an account that has permission to create new users.

Comment: mysql> GRANT ALL ON `exilog`.* TO 'exilog'@'localhost';
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

p.s. i-m root

Comment: @CoffeeinTime I have the same erro, did you solve it?

Comment: FWIU this works for root because of the \*.\* which includes the 'mysql' db itself where users are stored - so root can create new users.

For a non-root user to do this, they too would need INSERT privileges on mysql.* I think. 

(Geting this problem trying to init a request-tracker 5 (aka rt5) database - the acl's portion of the DB setup is failing I think because it's trying to create a user (itself?) with no permissions to do so. FWIW 'grant INSERT on mysql.* to 'rt_admin'@'localhost'; flush privileges; then rt-setup-database action acl,core,insert worked - now I remove INSERT privs.)

Answer (score 1):

- ubuntu 22.04.1
- Mysql Ver 8.0.31-0

My root had no GRANT privileges so I could not grant new users any previlegies.
Solution was to Drop current root user and create new one using 'mysql_native_password'.

Commands as follows
Login to mysql with as root

```
mysql> DROP USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' FROM mysql.user;
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter option:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: Requires some details as to why this is better then the accepted solution. As written it needs some references as well.